# Integrating Laravel 5.4 and Angular 1 with Paypal Vault

Tags: php, angularjs, laravel, paypal

I'm trying to understand what would be the best way to integrate PayPal Vault with my site.

First, I don't need to process payments. The only thing I need to do is to temporary save credit card numbers (that will serve as a guarantee), and I don't want to do that on my servers.

I've found Paypal Vault, which I think would work just perfectly.

Now, there's lots of material on the web, probably too much on the argument, at the point that it started confusing me, instead of really helping me.

In terms of design, I'd prefer to don't even let those data go through my servers, so having a library doing everything somehow at client side would be great, but I'm not sure if that's possible.

Of course, I've created my tokens in Paypal, and I've tried to work on Vault using the REST APIs (with CURL), no problems with that.

I've seen there are a bunch of different libraries.
* PayPal and Braintree recently merged, thing which doesn't really make me anymore understand if I should use the PayPal APIs or the Braintree APIs
* Laravel has an official package called cashier, which doesn't mention Vault support
* PayPal provides an official PHP library
* Lots of people developed lots of custom packages on GitHub, both for Laravel and Angular. But given the type of data those libraries will need to manage, I'd really prefer to have a second opinion from someone who went through this.

Any experience, thought, suggestion would be very appreciated!

Thank you

Comment: PayPal and Braintree are the same company, but different services, their APIs aren't going to be compatible.

Comment: Yes I know..From what I've understood Braintree seems to be an abstraction on top of the Paypal APIs...so still I might want to choose either one or the other for the project.

Comment: Well, the choice should be easy... if you're using Braintree, use Braintree API, if you're using PayPal, use the PayPal API.  I guess I'm not sure where the confusion lies, you can't use Braintree's API if you're not subscribed to Braintree.

Comment: For example, going more deeper, I've just discovered now that Vault has been removed from the Paypal PHP SDK, and moved to Braintree. So there's no more choice here. I've to integrate with Braintree.